# FFMPEG change audio channel tag for MOV file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having difficulty renaming audio stream on MOV (works fine on MP4).
As you can see during the run it shows expected result - audio stream 2 labelled as 'div', but when I check using ffprobe all the streams are labelled 'eng'.
Below is the code that I use.

```
PS C:\Tools\ffmpeg-20160224-git-10fa50c-win64-static\bin>  .\ffmpeg.exe  -i C:\Users\dan\Downloads\IceRoadDVTest2.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -metadata:s:a:1 language=div -qp 0 TEST2_copy.mov
ffmpeg version N-78646-g10fa50c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab
le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
ble-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 24.106 / 57. 24.106
  libavformat    57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 35.100 /  6. 35.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.2 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\dan\Downloads\IceRoadDVTest2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
    com.apple.finalcutstudio.media.uuid: 34E5E804-CFCA-47F4-9F88-38A1AF158F12
  Duration: 00:01:00.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53086 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) (xd5b / 0x62356478), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 49997 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : XDCAM HD422 1080i60 (50 Mb/s)
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:42
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
Output #0, mov, to 'TEST2_copy.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.finalcutstudio.media.uuid: 34E5E804-CFCA-47F4-9F88-38A1AF158F12
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (xd5b / 0x62356478), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 49997 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : XDCAM HD422 1080i60 (50 Mb/s)
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(div): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-23 16:12:25
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1807 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  390647kB time=00:01:00.29 bitrate=53076.7kbits/s speed=99.2x
video:367986kB audio:22610kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.013180%


PS C:\Tools\ffmpeg-20160224-git-10fa50c-win64-static\bin> .\ffprobe.exe .\TEST2_copy.mov
ffprobe version N-78646-g10fa50c Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enab
le-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
ble-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 24.106 / 57. 24.106
  libavformat    57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 35.100 /  6. 35.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\TEST2_copy.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53076 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) (xd5b / 0x62356478), yuv422p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 49997 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : XDCAM HD422 1080i60 (50 Mb/s)
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
```

Comment: Apparently only some [ISO 639-2 3-letter language codes](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) are accepted. Is there a non-FFmpeg muxer you can try that does accept any/all of these language codes? A brief look at [`libavformat/isom.c`](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavformat/isom.c;h=2ca126585feb4c34fc73c767d433122030950306;hb=HEAD#l336) shows a partial array of language codes, but I'm not yet sure if it is a bug with ffmpeg or a limitation of the [spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/Metadata/Metadata.html).

Comment: Well, the 'div' code works if the input and output is MP4.